# Can I make this bash script shorter?

Tags: bash

We created extensions for Chrome, Firefox and Safari and we want to test our extensions with Selenium. I created about 15 Selenium tests, and we want to run them with crontab every 8 hours (we might want to change to 4 hours later). I want to receive the results of each test by email, and we also want to receive a daily report every day after the tests of 8:15 AM are over. Here are my scripts (I'm only showing the first two tests):

**run_daily_selenium_tests.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

today_date_hour=`TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H"`
start_hour=`TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date +"%H"`

cd /home/ubuntu/selenium_tests
python /home/ubuntu/selenium_tests/tests/chrome_inbox_without_extension_test.py >/home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/"$today_date_hour"_chrome_inbox_without_extension_test.log 2>&1
cat /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/"$today_date_hour"_chrome_inbox_without_extension_test.log | mail -s "Chrome Inbox Without Extension Test - `TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`" <my_email_address>
python /home/ubuntu/selenium_tests/tests/chrome_inbox_1_with_extension_test.py >/home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/"$today_date_hour"_chrome_inbox_1_with_extension_test.log 2>&1
cat /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/"$today_date_hour"_chrome_inbox_1_with_extension_test.log | mail -s "Chrome Inbox 1 With Extension Test - `TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`" <my_email_address>

if [ $start_hour = "08" ]; then
    cd /home/ubuntu
    /home/ubuntu/scripts/send_daily_report.sh
fi
```

**print_daily_report.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

today=`TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
yesterday=`TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "yesterday"`

cd /home/ubuntu
echo "Chrome Inbox Without Extension Test - $today: `ls -1 /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$yesterday\"_1*_chrome_inbox_without_extension_test.log /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$yesterday\"_2*_chrome_inbox_without_extension_test.log /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$today\"_0*_chrome_inbox_without_extension_test.log | wc -l` tests total, `fgrep -l -v FAILED /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$yesterday\"_1*_chrome_inbox_without_extension_test.log /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$yesterday\"_2*_chrome_inbox_without_extension_test.log /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$today\"_0*_chrome_inbox_without_extension_test.log | wc -l` passed, `fgrep -l FAILED /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$yesterday\"_1*_chrome_inbox_without_extension_test.log /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$yesterday\"_2*_chrome_inbox_without_extension_test.log /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$today\"_0*_chrome_inbox_without_extension_test.log | wc -l` failed."
echo "Chrome Inbox 1 With Extension Test - $today: `ls -1 /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$yesterday\"_1*_chrome_inbox_1_with_extension_test.log /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$yesterday\"_2*_chrome_inbox_1_with_extension_test.log /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$today\"_0*_chrome_inbox_1_with_extension_test.log | wc -l` tests total, `fgrep -l -v FAILED /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$yesterday\"_1*_chrome_inbox_1_with_extension_test.log /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$yesterday\"_2*_chrome_inbox_1_with_extension_test.log /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$today\"_0*_chrome_inbox_1_with_extension_test.log | wc -l` passed, `fgrep -l FAILED /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$yesterday\"_1*_chrome_inbox_1_with_extension_test.log /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$yesterday\"_2*_chrome_inbox_1_with_extension_test.log /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/\"$today\"_0*_chrome_inbox_1_with_extension_test.log | wc -l` failed."
```

**send_daily_report.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

today=`TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date +"%Y-%m-%d"`

cd /home/ubuntu
/home/ubuntu/scripts/print_daily_report.sh 2>&1 | mail -s "Selenium Tests Daily Report - $today" <my_email_address>
```

I have two problem with the scripts above:

1. If the log file doesn't exist, I receive an error message "No such file or directory", I want to redirect errors to dev/null.
2. The lines in **print_daily_report.sh** are too long, is it possible to make them shorter? Each line contains 9 files with wildcards, they are the same files repeated 3 times.

By the way, I prefer not to change **send_daily_report.sh** to redirect errors to dev/null but to change only **print_daily_report.sh**.

**Update**: If I add `2>/dev/null` before `wc -l` in **print_daily_report.sh**, I don't receive error messages, but for some tests (We only ran the tests once today), I receive "1 tests total, 1 passed, 1 failed.". I checked and the test failed, but I want to count the number of files which don't contain the word "FAILED", how do I do it? (my command `fgrep -l -v FAILED` is not correct)

**Solution**: I found a solution based on the two answers below. Here is my solution (I only changed the first two scripts):

**run_daily_selenium_tests.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/ubuntu/selenium_tests

today_date_hour=`TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H"`
start_hour=`TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date +"%H"`
selenium_test_prefix="/home/ubuntu/selenium_tests/tests/"
selenium_test_suffix=".py"
log_prefix="/home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/"

run_selenium_test()
{
    selenium_test_file_name="${selenium_test_prefix}${file_name}${selenium_test_suffix}"
    log_suffix="_${file_name}.log"
    log_file_name="${log_prefix}${today_date_hour}${log_suffix}"
    python "$selenium_test_file_name" >"$log_file_name" 2>&1
    cat "$log_file_name" | mail -s "$test_name - `TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`" <my_email_address>
}

file_name="chrome_inbox_without_extension_test"
test_name="Chrome Inbox Without Extension Test"
run_selenium_test

file_name="chrome_inbox_1_with_extension_test"
test_name="Chrome Inbox 1 With Extension Test"
run_selenium_test

if [ $start_hour = "08" ]; then
    cd /home/ubuntu
    /home/ubuntu/scripts/send_daily_report.sh
fi
```

**print_daily_report.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/ubuntu

today=`TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
yesterday=`TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "yesterday"`
log_prefix="/home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/"

print_test_results()
{
    log_suffix="_${file_name}.log"
    yesterday_logs="${log_prefix}${yesterday}_[1,2]*${log_suffix}"
    today_logs="${log_prefix}${today}_0*${log_suffix}"
    echo -n "$test_name - $today: `ls -1 $yesterday_logs $today_logs 2>/dev/null | wc -l 2>/dev/null` tests total, "
    echo -n "`fgrep -L FAILED $yesterday_logs $today_logs 2>/dev/null | wc -l 2>/dev/null` passed, "
    echo "`fgrep -l FAILED $yesterday_logs $today_logs 2>/dev/null | wc -l 2>/dev/null` failed."
}

file_name="chrome_inbox_without_extension_test"
test_name="Chrome Inbox Without Extension Test"
print_test_results

file_name="chrome_inbox_1_with_extension_test"
test_name="Chrome Inbox 1 With Extension Test"
print_test_results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shorten your lines in `print_daily_report.sh`, you could create some variables of the repeated information. For example you could have these variables:

```
suffix="/home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/"
prefix="chrome_inbox_without_extension_test.log"
yesterdayLogs="${prefix}\"$yesterday\"_[1,2]*_${suffix}"
todayLogs="${prefix}\"$today\"_0*_${suffix}"
```

This could make your first echo line look like this:

```
echo "Chrome Inbox Without Extension Test - $today: `ls -1 $yesterdayLogs $todayLogs | wc -l` tests total, `fgrep -L FAILED $yesterdayLogs $todayLogs | wc -l` passed, `fgrep -l FAILED $yesterdayLogs $todayLogs | wc -l` failed."
```

You could also split this echo into multiple lines and still get the same output like so:

```
echo -n "Chrome Inbox Without Extension Test - $today: `ls -1 $yesterdayLogs $todayLogs | wc -l` tests total,"
echo -n "`fgrep -L FAILED $yesterdayLogs $todayLogs | wc -l` passed,"
echo "`fgrep -l FAILED $yesterdayLogs $todayLogs | wc -l` failed."
```

The `-n` option for echo means that it does not print a newline at the end. You should be able to apply this same technique to shorten your second echo statement as well but I figured I'd let you play with that to hone your Bash skills.

For error suppression, I would recommend redirecting `stderr` when calling the script. So your line would become

```
/home/ubuntu/scripts/print_daily_report.sh 2>/dev/null | mail -s "Selenium Tests Daily Report - $today" <my_email_address>
```

This would give you the same results you are getting, but without any error output. I know you did not want to change the `send_daily_report.sh` file, but this will be the easiest way to do what you want and there really isn't a reason not too (so far as I can see). If you don't do this, you'll have to add the redirection line to all of your commands, so your echo statements would turn into this:

```
echo -n "Chrome Inbox Without Extension Test - $today: `ls -1 $yesterdayLogs $todayLogs 2>/dev/null | wc -l 2>/dev/null` tests total,"
echo -n "`fgrep -L FAILED $yesterdayLogs $todayLogs 2>/dev/null | wc -l 2>/dev/null` passed,"
echo "`fgrep -l FAILED $yesterdayLogs $todayLogs 2>/dev/null | wc -l 2>/dev/null` failed."
```

Comment: Hi, please notice my updated question - `fgrep -l -v FAILED` is not correct. I want to count the number of files which don't contain the word "FAILED".

Comment: The fgrep command you gave is working for me. `fgrep -l -v FAILED` and `fgrep -L FAILED` should work. What makes you think it isn't working correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're seeing that happen. Both forms of the fgrep command are working fine for me on an Ubuntu system.

Comment: `fgrep -L FAILED` works but `fgrep -l -v FAILED` doesn't. It counts files which have lines without the word "FAILED" (even if the file contains the word "FAILED").

Comment: Okay now I see what you mean. I've updated my answer to have `fgrep -L FAILED` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is two easy steps to improve your scripts, both in readability and maintainability:

1. Do not use backticks, but this form of `$(expansion)`, it
    is much easier to read and to nest into other expressions.
2. Use functions to structure your code, so that you can debug
    functionalities individually and give names to complex
    operations.

Not everyone agrees with this, but I also recommend to beginners always to
prefer `printf` over `echo`, it is both more powerful and easier to use.

Here would be a first rewrite – up to the first report – of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

today=$(TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date +"%Y-%m-%d")
yesterday=$(TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "yesterday")

test_report()
{
    local total passed failed

    total=$(ls -1 "$@" | wc)
    passed=$(fgrep -L FAILED "$@" | wc)
    failed=$(fgrep -l FAILED "$@" | wc)

    printf 'Chrome Inbox Without Extension Test - %s: ' "${today}"
    printf '%s tests total, %s passed, %s failed.\n'\
           "${total}" "${passed}" "${failed}"
}

test_report\
    /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/"${yesterday}"_1*_chrome_inbox_without_extension_test.log\
    /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/"{$yesterday}"_2*_chrome_inbox_without_extension_test.log\
    /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests/"${today}"_0*_chrome_inbox_without_extension_test.log
```

This closely follows your original script, and also has the drawback that it will produce garbage if no test is present.

There is a more idiosyncratic way to solve your problem: first compute raw data about our test results and then aggregate it. In our specific case, this means writing a function `test_analyse` that prepares a table with two rows, the name of a test and ling a flag telif it is failed or passed. Then we can aggregate over this table to produce a final report. The last step is typically accomplished with **Awk** – this is essentially what **Awk** is for – but you can basically use your favourite scripting language here, even the shell.

```
#!/bin/bash

TODAY=$(TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date +"%Y-%m-%d")
YESTERDAY=$(TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "yesterday")

test_analyse()
{
    local today yesterday extension testdir
    local testlog testresult

    testdir=""

    yesterday="$1"
    toady="$2"

    if [ "$3" = 'yes' ]; then
        extension='with_extension'
    else
        extension='without_extension'
    fi

    find /home/ubuntu/logs/selenium_tests\
         -name "${yesterday}_1*_chrome_inbox_${extension}_test.log"\
         -o -name "${yesterday}_2*_chrome_inbox_${extension}_test.log"\
         -o -name "${today}_0*_chrome_inbox_${extension}_test.log" \
        | while read testlog; do
              if grep -q 'FAILED' "${testlog}"; then
                  testresult='FAILED'
              else
                  testresult='PASSED'
              fi
              printf '%s|%s\n' "${testlog}" "${testresult}"
          done
}

test_report()
{
    test_analyse "$@" | awk -F '|' -v today="$2" -v extension="$3" '
{t+=1}
$2 ~ /FAILED/ {f+=1}
$2 ~ /PASSED/ {p+=1}
END {
 if(extension == "yes") {
   complement = "With Extension"
 } else {
   complement = "Without Extension"
 }
 print "Chrome Inbox " complement " Test = " today ": "\
   t " tests total, " p " passed, " f " failed."
'
}

test_report "${YESTERDAY}" "${TODAY}" 'no'
test_report "${YESTERDAY}" "${TODAY}" 'yes'
```

Comment: Hi, please notice my updated question - `fgrep -l -v FAILED` is not correct. I want to count the number of files which don't contain the word "FAILED".

Comment: @Uri Yes, you actually want to `fgrep -L`.

Comment: Thank you. Also notice, I have 15 tests, not only 2 tests (without extension and with extension), each test has a different log file name.